# Proof that $A=B$ if eigenvalues and eigenvectors are the same

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

The prompt:

> Suppose $A$ and $B$ have the same eigenvalues $\lambda_1, \dots, \lambda_n$ with the same independent eigenvectors $x_1, \cdots, x_n$. Then $A = B$. Reason: Any vector $\mathbf{x}$ is a combination $c_1 \mathbf{x}_1+ \cdots + c_n \mathbf{x}_n$. What is $A\mathbf x$? What is $B \mathbf x$?

What I think the answer is is supposed to be is

$Ax = v = \lambda_1 c_1 \mathbf{x_1} + \cdots + \lambda_n c_n \mathbf{x_n} = Bx$

I want to verify that what this is saying is that any vector can be broken up into eigenvectors of A (when the eigenvalues are independent). Each of these eigenvectors has an eigenvalue associated with it, and since the eigenvalues and the eigenvectors are the same, then this must also be $Bx$.

Is that reasoning correct? If so, I guess I haven't yet convinced myself that the order of the columns must be the same. I know for the proof to be correct that if the eigenvectors are independent and the eigenvalues are the same than this solution must be unique but since I haven't proven it to myself yet I feel sneaky using it in the proof...

Comment: What kind of matrices are $A$ and $B$?

Comment: Yes, your reasoning to show that $Ax=Bx$ for any $x$ is correct. To see that $A$ and $B$ have the same columns just note that $Ae_i$ is the $i$ column of $A$.

Comment: What happens if your matrices are defective?